# Use css only to accomplish this layout

Tags: css

at first I thought it was easy, until I tried...

is there some god of css can help me lol

I finished the outside, But I got one tsudo content only, how to set two stars and one word into that....?(not a real button, just look like it will be fine)

[image: use css only(and 1 html tag)]

i post what I did so far, and sorry for described it unclearly, It look like a button, not a  lol.

```css
#foo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 101px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px lightgrey;
}

#foo::before {
  content: "";
  color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 93px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(161, 161, 161);
  /* box-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(134, 134, 134); */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(230, 228, 228) 53%, rgb(199, 199, 199) 55%);
}

#foo {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rgb(209, 206, 206);
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

Comment: For the stars, you can use [HTML entity characters](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). `&bigstar;` is star.

Comment: can you just not add a span inside your div and add the stars as pseudo elements to that?

Answer (score 7):

something like this:

the secret is to use multiple box shadows to get the outline of the box.

and to use linear-gradient background

now you can use `::after` and `::before` to add the text (checkout, stars)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@800&display=swap');
#foo::after {
  content: "checkout";
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555555;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#foo::before {
  content: "★                    ★";
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 80%);
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 1.25em
}

#foo {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #AEAEAE, #C4C4C4 48%, #D5D5D5 52%, #E1E1E1);
  border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #616161, 0 0 0 4px #CBCBCB, 0 0 0 5.5px #FFFFFF, 0 0 0 7px #555555;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

Comment: I would also add `text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 80%)` to the text and the stars to add the embossing effect.